# Darf man im Frauensport von "Mannschaft" reden?

Tags: single-word-request

Anlässlich der Frauenfußball-WM hört man häufig den Begriff "Mannschaft":

> Die japanische Mannschaft hat wunderbar gespielt.

Nun findet sich aber auch folgende Umschreibung:

> Das Team der deutschen Fußballerinnen hat...

Die Umschreibung mittels "Team" kommt aber auch wie folgt vor:

> Das Team der amerikanischen Mannschaft...

Alle Formulierungen erscheinen irgendwie unglücklich. Darf man - oder soll man sogar - im Frauensport von einer "Mannschaft" reden?

Comment: Es ist doch _die_ Mannschaft `;-)`

Comment: Apropos. Dazu könnte man auch mal wieder wunderbar eine Rede beginnen: *Liebe Mitgliederinnen und Mitglieder*. @Hendrik Vogt: Sehr hübsch entdeckt :)

Comment: `Dürfen` bedarf hier der näheren Erläuterung. Man darf Dir nicht verbieten von einer Mannschaft zu reden - so was ist hier gemeint? Ein feministischer Standpunkt? Gibt es für Frauen eine andere Sprache? Soll es die geben? `Die Frauschaft`? Gibt es eine DFB-Direktive, die besagt, dass Offizielle Vertreterinnen und Vertreter des Frauenfussballs 'Mannschaft' meiden sollen? Bei den Fernsehanstalten? Gebietet es der Anstand?

Comment: Team und Mannschaft sind nicht exakt dasselbe. Trainer, Masseur, Wasserträger usw. gehören zum Team aber nicht zur Mannschaft. Aber ich gebe zu, dass das eine Spitzfindigkeit ist

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich finde das nicht spitzfindig, sondern eine wichtige Feststellung.

Comment: [Es ist unbestritten, dass Sprache diskriminiert](http://www.scilogs.de/wblogs/blog/sprachlog/sprachstruktur/2011-11-30/sprache-diskriminiert) und mithin auch sexistisch ist. Soweit ich weiß sprechen allerdings auch Frauen von ihren Teams als Mannschaften. Ob das Wort eine diskriminierende Wirkung hat, kann man leicht an sich selbst testen: einen Satz mit Mannschaft (am besten _ohne_ Sportart) bilden, der weder Männer noch Frauen explizit erwähnt, und überprüfen, an was für eine Gruppe Menschen man spontan denkt.

Comment: @Clemens: In dem Setting möchte ich jemanden sehen, der spontan und unbefangen noch an etwas denken kann. Ich würde sagen, der Anstoß muss von außen kommen.

Comment: @userunknown mir fallen spontan drei Varianten ein, bei denen ich jedes mal eine andere Gruppe vor Augen habe.

Comment: Was ist am *diskriminieren* schlecht? Das heißt ganz einfach *unterscheiden*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ja, darf man. Es gibt sogar das relativ gebräuchliche Wort "Frauenmannschaft".

Comment: +1, kurz und auf den Punkt.

Answer (score 8):

Natürlich darf man. Mannschaft ist ein feststehender Begriff, der natürlich von Männern kommt, aber heute allgemein für Personen steht. Das ist wie im Management-Jargon; natürlich kann man sich anstellen und politisch korrekt "Personentage" sagen - aber "Manntage" ist immer noch korrekt, auch wenn nur Frauen an dem Projekt arbeiten. Ein Panzer ist ja auch bemannt, wenn nur Frauen drin sind :)

Natürlich kannst du statt der japanischen Mannschaft einfach von den Japanerinnen sprechen - eine Formulierung, die ich eigentlich fast besser finde. "Team der amerikanischen Mannschaft" hingegen ist irgendwie albern - das wäre besser als "Team der Amerikaner" (Achtung: Die Amerikaner sind hier alle Amerikaner - Männer wie Frauen -, so dass die männliche Form als neutrale Form verwendet wird) oder "das amerikanische Team" beschrieben.

Comment: US-Amerikaner? Meine Südamerikanerinnen sind ja auch Amerikaner. Im Fußball auch keine zu vernachlässigende Größe, auch wenn die US-Mädels da eine Rolle spielen, im Ggs. zu den Herren. Apropos Herren: Bei der Altherrenmannschaft des Damenfußballs wird's aber langsam komisch. :)

Comment: Aber Altdamenmannschaft des Damenfußballs klingt irgendwie... nach schlechtem Stil.

Comment: "Natürlich kannst du statt der japanischen Mannschaft einfach von den Japanerinnen sprechen" - ist denn die Mitgliedschaft in der Mannschaft eines Landes in jedem Fall zwingend an die Staatsbürgerschaft oder eine sonstige Zugehörigkeit zum Land gebunden? Mein Eindruck (als zugegebenermaßen absolut nicht sportaffiner Mensch) war seither, dass Spieler diverser Sportarten munter global zwischen Teams weiterverkauft werden.

Answer (score 1):

Der CVJM änderte im Laufe seiner Geschichte die Bedeutung der Abkürzung von "Christlicher Verein Junger Männer" in "Christlicher Verein Junger Menschen". Daher: Wie wäre es mit "Menschschaft"? ;)

Comment: Und was macht der YMCA?

Answer (score 0):

Gerade wurde ein Artikel auf Bild-Online veröffentlicht:

**Sollen wir statt Mannschaft jetzt „Frauschaft“ sagen?**

> Wir sollen jetzt von „Frauschaften“ statt von Mannschaften sprechen,
> wenn die Mitglieder einer Mannschaft weiblich sind. Das regt zumindest
> das ZDF-Sportstudio bei Instagram an.

https://www.bild.de/politik/inland/politik-inland/zdf-sportstudio-regt-an-sollen-wir-statt-mannschaft-jetzt-frauschaft-sagen-78686936.bild.html